# Angular 6 passing in parameters into URL

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

So I have an angular app that currently has a route such "urlname/stockdata". I would like to be able to pass in a stock symbol into that url such as "urlname/stockdata/AAPL". My app is making a call to a third party API with that symbol. Do you guys have any advice on how I can do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can declare a route with parameters like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'urlname/stockdata/:id', component: MyComp}
];
```

Create a link in the template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/urlname/stockdata', id]">MyLink</a>
```

Or navigate from the `.ts`:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/urlname/stockdata', id]);
```

---

Then you can read it with:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.id = params['id'];
});
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  Question:  How do I make this work with a direct url?  I get an error: "Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/userAdmin/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Answer (score 1):

TS File

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  children: [{
    path: 'plans/:id',
    component: PlanListComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]
  }]
}];
```

HTML

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="viewDetails(product.id)">View Detail</a>
```

TS

```
 viewDetails (productId) {
        this.router.navigate([ BASE_URL +"/plans/" + productId]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , consider you have to send 4 parameters in URL for eg. **Zone**, **State**, **MP** & **JC** .
For this go to file
**sample.component.ts**

```
 functionName() {
 let param={
      zone:this.selectZone,
      state:this.selectState,
      jc:this.stateJC,
      mp:this.MPdata
    }

 this.availservice.AvailReport(param)
      .subscribe((json) => {
      this.ArrayResponse= json;
      } );
}
```

Now come to file
**sample.service.ts**

```
 AvailReport(param) {  
let UrlTemp= `http://11.111.11.11:3838/getdata/AVAILABILITY_${param.zone}_${param.state}_${param.jc}_${param.mp}.JSON?callback=true`;
    return this.http.get(UrlTemp);
  }
```

For sure your will get response like :

```
Request URL: http://10.141.55.49:3838/getdata/AVAILABILITY_ZoneName_StateName_MPName_JCName.JSON?callback=true
```

Using this method you pass any number of parameters in URL & Ask your backend team to recieve the parameters.